# How to call vars on an instance to also have vars called on attributes that are also instances

Tags: python, python-3.x

How do I get `vars` function to return the properties of a `class` if a property is of type another class?

Example:

```
class User:
    def __init__(self, first_name, last_name):
        self.first_name = first_name
        self.last_name = last_name
        self.geo = GeoInformation()


class GeoInformation:
    def __init__(self, city="", state="", zipcode="", country=""):
        self.city = city
        self.state = state
        self.zipcode = zipcode
        self.country = country


user = User("John", "Smith")
user.geo.city = "SomeCity"
user.geo.state = "SomeState"
user.geo.zipcode = "SomeZipcode"
user.geo.country = "SomeCountry"

print(vars(user))
```

Output I am getting:

```
{'first_name': 'John', 'last_name': 'Smith', 'geo': <class '__main__.GeoInformation'>}
```

Output I am expecting:

```
{'first_name': 'John', 'last_name': 'Smith', 'geo': {'city':'someCity', 'state':'someState', 'zipcode':'someZipcode', 'country':'someCountry'}}
```

If this is not the right way to do what I am trying to achieve, please suggest the better way.

Comment: Why did you expect that? Also, I'm pretty sure you meant `self.geo = GeoInformation()`, but that wouldn't give you the output you were expecting either. It seems like you want to convert an object into a nested dictionary, so to do that, you'll have to write your own function.

Comment: I am trying to insert this data into `mongodb` and it requires the object as second output.

Comment: Note, also, your `first_name` property is being returned as a `str` object, not a `dict`. This contradicts your desired output of "all the properties of a class as dict even if there exists a property which is of another class?".

Comment: Then write a function to do what you need. This isn't what `vars` is for, which simply returns the `__dict__` property of the object you pass in, which will correspond to the namespace of the object if it exists.

Comment: Instead of trying to find a magic function that does everything that you want, maybe you should try writing a function that solves exactly the problem you have.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a function to run `vars` recursively and return the result:

```
def recursive_vars(obj):
    dct = vars(obj)
    for k, v in dct.items():
        if hasattr(v, "__dict__"):  # check if we can go further recursively
            dct[k] = recursive_vars(v)
    return dct
```

Now, any value that was a class should be replaced by whatever `vars()` would have produced for that class, and so on down the chain.

Comment: Um, why `inspect.isclass(v)`?

Comment: well, `isinstance(obj, type)` would work, but that is almost *certainly* not what the OP wants. And note, it wouldn't give the output they were looking for (assuming you mean to use `dct` instead of `init_vars` which is undefined, and you meant to iterate over `dct.items()`).

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga upon further inspection, you're absolutely right. I've fixed problems, and replaced `inspect.isclass()` with just a check for if it has a `__dict__` attribute, which is the prerequisite for `vars()` to work anyway

Answer (score 0):

You could define a `__repr__` method in your GeoInformation class that calls var on itself so when you call `print(vars(user))` it will also print out the data in your geo property

```
class User:
    def __init__(self, first_name, last_name,city, state, zipcode, country):
        self.first_name = first_name
        self.last_name = last_name
        self.geo = GeoInformation(city, state, zipcode, country)

class GeoInformation:
    def __init__(self, city="", state="", zipcode="", country=""):
        self.city = city
        self.state = state
        self.zipcode = zipcode
        self.country = country
    def __repr__(self):
        return str(vars(self))


user = User("John", "Smith","SomeCity","SomeState","SomeZipcode","SomeCountry")


print(vars(user))
```

Output:

```
{'first_name': 'John', 'last_name': 'Smith', 'geo': {'city': 'SomeCity', 'state': 'SomeState', 'zipcode': 'SomeZipcode', 'country': 'SomeCountry'}}
```

Comment: But this is not what the OP wants. The op wants a function that returns that *object*, not an object that will get *printed* that way.